# Braces in regexp for ruby sub-method block

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have a string:

```
s = "<aaa>bbb</ccc>"
```

I want to get aaa and bbb in ruby block for sub method.
If I call:

```
s.sub(/<([a-z]+)>([\s\S]+)<\/[a-z]+>/,"first=\\1 second=\\2")
```

everything works as I expect, so the output is "first=aaa second=bbb".
Then I call the same regexp with ruby-block, but it returns only the whole string but not \\1 and \\2 parts:

```
s.sub(/<([a-z]+)>([\s\S]+)<\/[a-z]+>/) { |x,y| puts x; puts y; }
```

This case output is

```
<aaa>bbb</ccc>, nil.
```

How can I get sentences in braces like \\1, \\2 in ruby-block for sub method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string yielded by `sub` will always be the full match. To get at the captures, you can use `$1` and `$2` inside the block.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want.